# Firebase cloud function unit test timing out

Tags: typescript, firebase, unit-testing, jestjs

I'm trying to write tests for my firebase function, and I'm running into jest timing out:

```
 ● testing random number › works

    thrown: "Exceeded timeout of 5000 ms for a test.
    Use jest.setTimeout(newTimeout) to increase the timeout value, if this is a long-running test."

      19 |   });
      20 |
    > 21 |   it('works', async () => {
         |   ^
      22 |     const generateRandomNumber = testEnv.wrap(funcs.generateRandomNumber);
      23 |
      24 |     const { randomNumber } = await generateRandomNumber({});

      at __tests__/index.test.ts:21:3
      at Object.<anonymous> (__tests__/index.test.ts:10:1)
```

I'm also receiving these warnings:

```
console.warn 
[2021-08-31T21:59:06.437Z]  @firebase/database: FIREBASE WARNING: Provided authentication credentials
for the app named "[DEFAULT]" are invalid. This usually indicates your app was not initialized
correctly. Make sure the "credential" property provided to initializeApp() is authorized to access the
specified "databaseURL" and is from the correct project.
```

even when I set my timeout to 60s, the test simply waits that long before timing out. The interesting thing is that my `generateRandomNumber` function *is actually modifying the DB*, I can watch it work from the firebase console. Something to note would be that I'm pointing to a different project for the tests than I am regularly, as the Firebase docs recommend doing.

my file structure looks like this:

```
src
  index.ts
  __tests__/
    google_auth_key.json
    index.test.ts
```

`index.ts`

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';

const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

export const database = admin.database().ref();

export const generateRandomNumber = functions.https.onCall(
  async(data: any, context) => {
    const randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100)
    await database.child('random_numbers').push(randomNumber)

    return { randomNumber }
  }
);
```

`indext.test.ts`

```
import functionsTest from 'firebase-functions-test';

const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const testEnv = functionsTest({
  "databaseURL": "https://hivemind-test-a83fc-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com",
  "projectId": "hivemind-test-a83fc",
}, './google_auth_key.json');

describe('testing random number', () => {
  let funcs: any;

  beforeAll(() => {
    funcs = require('../index.ts');
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    admin.database().ref('random_numbers').remove();
  });

  it('works', async () => {
    const generateRandomNumber = testEnv.wrap(funcs.generateRandomNumber);

    const { randomNumber } = await generateRandomNumber({});

    console.log(randomNumber);

    const data = await admin.database().ref('random_numbers').once('value');

    const dbRandomNumber = Object.values(data.val())[0];
    expect(dbRandomNumber).toBe(randomNumber);
  })
})
```

Comment: it seems to work if I plug in the `credentials` and `databaseURL` of the test project directly into `initializeApp`. How come my `functionsTest()()` doesn't handle this properly?

Comment: I decided not to use a whole new project for testing, I just created a new database on my existing database, that way I can use the same credentials and just update the database url.